# Sections of quotient groups and semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider a quotient group $G/H$. If there is a section that is a subgroup of $G$ (I mean a transversal that is also a group), must the group be necessarily a semidirect (including direct) product?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is but I'm guessing the answer has something to do with the splitting lemma. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupExtension.html) for some information.

Comment: If there is a transversal $T$ of $H$ in $G$ that is a subgroup of $G$, then $T$ is a complement of $H$ in $G$, so the extension is split, and is isomorphic/equal to a semidirect product of $H$ by $T$.

Comment: note TH = G and $T\cap H = \{e\}$ and H is normal. one can define the homomorphism from T to Aut(H) explicitly by conjugating h in H by t in T.

Answer (score 1):

As the enterprise of offering redemption to tormented questions out of unanswered questions's hell requires, I'll just write down as an answer the comments by Derek and David:

We have a group $\,G\,\,,\,\,H\triangleleft G\,$ and $\,T\,$ a transversal of $\,H\,$ in $\,G\,$, meaning:
$$G/H=\{tH\;\;;\;\;t\in T\}$$

If $\,T\leq G\,$, then$$G=TH\,\,,\,\,T\cap H=\{1\}\,\,and\,\,H\triangleleft G\Longrightarrow G=T\rtimes H$$